# Is this a real Indian fairy tale about a monkey who changes colour and marries a princess?

Tags: identification-request, short-stories, r-k-narayan, folk-tales

In R. K. Narayan's short story "A Willing Slave" (which I read as part of his 1982 collection [*Malgudi Days*](https://eruditesdps.files.wordpress.com/2017/01/malgudi-days-narayan_-r-k_.pdf)), the nanny Ayah tells a story to the young girl Radha:

> The Ayah squatted below the cot and narrated the story of the black monkey which rolled in a sack of chalk powder, became white and married a princess; at the wedding somebody sprinkled water on him and he came out in his true colour; he was chased out; presently a [dhobi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhobi) took pity on him and washed, bleached and ironed him, in which state he regained the affection of the princess.

**Is this a real fairy tale told in some Indian culture?** I searched the internet for Indian stories about a black monkey and a princess, but failed to find anything that fits. Perhaps someone with more subject knowledge will know the answer.

Comment: I think there is indeed such a story. If I can find a source, I'll put it in an answer.